# XML Serialization Derived Types using value of an Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am modifying a set of classes that are being serialized, and I have a question that I cannot find the answer to.  The old classes had a very large class called Control that is further classified by a ControlType attribute

```
enum ControlType
{
    ControlType1 = 0,
    ControlType2 = 1
}

public class Control
{
    [XmlAttribute("a")]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("b")]
    public string b { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Type")]
    public ControlType Type {get; set;)
}
```

in the simplified sample above the original designer did not separate out the class into subclasses.  what we really want is

```
class baseControl
{
     [XmlAttribute("Type")]
     public ControlType Type {get; set;}
}

class Control1 : baseControl
{
    [XmlAttribute("a")]
    public string a { get; set; }
}

class Control2 : baseControl
{ 
    [XmlAttribute("b")]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

we want to separate out the classes but we want the original xml to be compatible

in the old hierarchy all controls types (defined by ControlType) were serialized as

```
<Control Type="ControlType1" a="xxxx" />
<Control Type="ControlType2" b="xxxxx" />
```

if we use the new structures obviously the new structure would look like

```
<Control1 Type="ControlType1" a="xxxx" />
<Control2 Type="ControlType2" b="xxxxx" />
```

but we really want to serialize all of the new derived classes as "Control" and when we deserialize we want to change the allocated type to the derived type based on the value of an Attribute.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can use the `[XmlElement("Control")]` to make sure that all of your control classes write out as `<Control ... >`.  I'm not sure if it's possible to make sure they all deserialize properly with the `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

The only chance to accomplish such behavior is to implemnent [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx) on the class corresponding to the *surrounding* element, and provide a custom (de)serialization behavior.

```
public class ControlContainer : IXmlSerializable
{
    // a single / array of / list of BaseControls
    public BaseControl Control { get; set; }

    // … any other properties

    // … implement IXmlSerializable here to have Control 
    // and any other properties (de)serialized
}
```

Comment: Okay this makes complete sense, but I have a question.  For the most part I want the standard serialization, the only thing I need to do is read the type and allocate the correct derived class.  How can I implement ReadXml() and call the base implementation of the Serializer and then do my magic.